# #, in [Maybe #, Letter]

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

It is a piece of data definition (comment) from the book *How to Design Programs* that teaches Scheme-like language and DrRacket IDE. What does `#,` inside `[Maybe #, Letter]` mean?

```
; A HMWord is [List-of [Maybe #, Letter]]

; A [Maybe X] is one of:
; – false
; – X
```

Comment: What chapter/section? Even better, link to the page on [the web site for the book](http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/) please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source is here:
http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_4.html

Looks like a typo to me, I think it should read:
`; A HMWord is [List-of [Maybe Letter]]`

But then it talks about underlines, although `LETTERS` does not contain any underline.
So I think here `false` should take the role of the underline (an unknown letter).

Comment: I have seen the term `,#` several times in the book, all in Maybe clauses. So it doesn't look a typo.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only other pieces of the book this `#,` appears is on the same page, for `; Attribute*.v3 is [#, List-of #, Attribute.v3]`, where it also looks like typos.

Also, the "#," has a specific meaning in Racket which is [`unsyntax`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html?q=unsyntax&q=syntax-unquote#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fqqstx..rkt%29._quasisyntax%29%29), and this is far too advanced for HtDP(2e), but could be very appropriate for someone _writing_ this book.

Comment: For what it's worth, [this has been confirmed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/racket-users/z2CMmsvJIHo) (and fixed in the draft version) by one of the authors.

Bottom line: just skip the `#,` things.

Comment: Wow, this topic caused the authors to make changes... There are plenty of typos throughout the book. I could not find the author's email address to notify them.

Comment: You should collect them and send them to the authors at some point. That would be very helpful.